# MySQL Query - multiple WHERE clause on 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

could anyone help me build up a query based on the query bellow.

As you can see I have a product with specifications and certain groups which are build up in the front-end. I know the problem, 1 column can't be 2 values at once but I need only those products that are in those 2 groups.

To illustrate, product_specification_sid, id 2 3 and 4 are sizes and de rest 8 ~ 11 are colors, so I would like to select a product that has 2 and 3.

Inner joining the table double isn't an option since the groups (sizes, colors) may vary in the future.

```
SELECT
    products.*,
    categories.*,
    manufacturers.* 
FROM products
INNER JOIN  product_categories ON product_category_pid = product_id
INNER JOIN  categories ON product_category_cid = category_id
INNER JOIN  manufacturers ON product_manufacturer = manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN  product_specifications ON product_specification_pid=product_id
WHERE 
    product_active = 1  
AND 
(
    product_specification_sid in (3)  
AND  
    product_specification_sid in (8,9,6,7,10,11)  
) 
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: I posted an answer that did the inner join twice. But then I read you statement that said you've already thought about that. I don't understand why you say it is not an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a having clause instead.

```
SELECT
    products.*,
FROM products
INNER JOIN  product_categories ON product_category_pid = product_id
INNER JOIN  categories ON product_category_cid = category_id
INNER JOIN  manufacturers ON product_manufacturer = manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN  product_specifications ON product_specification_pid=product_id
WHERE product_active = 1  
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product_specification_sid in (3) THEN 1 END) > 0
 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN product_specification_sid in (8,9,6,7,10,11) THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Should those having conditions be `> 1`? I would think `>= 1`/`> 0`, or `= 1`.

Comment: The query didnt work at first but @Sam DeHaan fixed it! I replaced the >1 bij >=1 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're looking for a product record that has two matching product_specification records meeting certain conditions. Sounds to me like the straightforward solution is:

```
SELECT products.*, categories.*, manufacturers.*  
FROM products
INNER JOIN  product_categories ON product_category_pid = product_id
INNER JOIN  categories ON product_category_cid = category_id
INNER JOIN  manufacturers ON product_manufacturer = manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN  product_specifications ps1 ON ps1.product_specification_pid=product_id
INNER JOIN  product_specifications ps2 ON ps2.product_specification_pid=product_id
WHERE      product_active = 1
  AND  ps1.product_specification_sid in (3)
  AND  ps2.product_specification_sid in (8,9,6,7,10,11)
```

By the way, that "group by" won't work. You have to group by everything that isn't an aggregate, and each table must have at least one column, so you have at least three non-aggregates. (Well, maybe MySQL has some extension here, but in standard SQL that would be rquired.)

Comment: like I said in the description, INNER joining isn't a (great) solution since it has to be dynamic in term of amount of groups of specifications. The query stated by @a'r did work and I am using MySQL as stated in the tags

Comment: If you've got a solution that works, great, no need to beat on it further. But I'm curious: Why does an inner join not work for you?

Comment: since I will get trouble with the results. If you want your method to work you should add
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2

To match it with 2 statements but if a sizes isn't available he will be able to match it of the colors are. So basically no medium but blue and black will give a (false) positive.

This was my first approach too :) Besides that, if I'm not mistaken all those innerjoins create a lot more load then the method above

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't understand your requirement. The above query would require that you have a 3 and that you have at least one of 8, 9, 6,, etc. Yes, you'd need a group-by to get only one record per product if it is possible to have both an 8 and a 9, e.g, but you wouldn't need a having count(*)>=2 unless you want to require that there be more than one. If you had exactly one 3 and one 8 and no other values, such a having would exclude the product from the list. Whether the counting is more efficient than two joins would depend on the nature of your data.

Comment: Anyway, as I say, I don't want to beat the subject to death if you have a solution that works. You've just got me curious now.